# Joint distribution of two events

Tags: self-study, joint-distribution

I am given a question as follows:

A fair coin is tossed 3 times. Let *A* be the number of heads and let *B* be the number of tails.

I am asked to find the joint probability distribution of *A* and *B*.

So I know for *A* and *B*, there are 4 possible outcomes each. *A*=0,1,2,3 and *B*=0,1,2,3. So in total there are 16 possible outcomes.

I have that (for 4 of the possible outcomes):

*P*(*A*=0, *B*=3) = *P*(*T*,*T*,*T*) = 1/16

*P*(*A*=1, *B*=2) = *P*(*H*,*T*,*T*) + *P*(*T*,*H*,*T*) + *P*(*T*,*T*,*H*) = 3/16

*P*(*A*=2, *B*=1) = *P*(*T*,*H*,*H*) + *P*(*H*,*T*,*H*) + *P*(*H*,*H*,*T*) = 3/16

*P*(*A*=3, *B*=0) = *P*(*H*,*H*,*H*) = 1/16

For the remaining 12 possible outcomes ((*A*=0, *B*=2), (*A*=1, *B*=3), etc), I got 0 and that clearly doesn't add up to 1. Can anybody help and see if I have made a mistake? Thank you.

Comment: When any coin, fair or not, is tossed three times, there are only $2\times 2\times 2 = 8$ possible outcomes, not $16$.

Comment: @whuber oh, then I must've gotten confused because of the word "joint" and assumed the total possibilities was 4 x 4 = 16. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You can list all the outcomes by giving the result of each toss in order...: HHH HHT HTH HTT THH THT TTH TTT  .... that's everything you can possibly get